# How to attach news_id to comment in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

comments_controller.rb:

```
 def create
@comment = Comment.create(comment_params)
if @comment.save
  redirect_to :back
else
  redirect_to :back
  flash[:error] = @comment.errors.full_messages
end
end
```

news_controller.rb:

```
def show
  @news = News.find(params[:id])
  @comment =  @news.comments.new
end
```

comment.rb:

```
belongs_to :news, dependent: :destroy
```

news.rb:

```
has_many :comments
```

How can i attach news_id to comments,if

```
@news = News.find(params[:id])
@comment = @news.comments.create(comment_params)
```

simply wont work,because

```
CommentsController#create Couldn't find News with 'id'=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure comment_params is sending what you're expecting?

It should have the correct `news_id` in it.

Make sure you pass the id of the `news` object in with the form for creating a comment. This can be done in a `hidden_field` (if you aren't already doing that). Assuming you're using form_helpers, if you have this:

```
f.hidden_field :news_id
```

Then the news_id should be coming into your `CommentController` properly.

You could do a

```
`raise "Boom: #{comment_params}"`
```

above

```
@comment = Comment.create(comment_params)
```

to make sure that it's coming in. Just submit a comment and the rails error page should show up with the params that it's getting.

Comment: yay,f.hidden_field :news_id helps

Answer (score 1):

What are your routes? You can nest resources which will pass the news_id with the form itself:

```
resources :news do
  resources :comments
end
```

Then you can do:

```
News.find(params[:news_id]).comments.create(comment_params)
```

A hidden field isn't the way to go I don't think, let rails do it for you.